# In zsh the date format for names isn't displayed properly

Tags: zsh, date, locale

I don't know what's wrong or if I'm stupid or something, but I just can't get to display the date with words :(

I've been trying this for hours now..

It should display Mon, but it displays a "M" with weird signs..
Every date format that is numeric works fine. It just doesn't display names for days and months.

my locale is set like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And this is inserted in RPROMPT for the display:
`%D{%a}`

Oh I almost forgot - when I press alt-f4 to get to the console, it displays the date format properly.

Comment: What do you see when you run the Unix `date` command?

Comment: Works for me. What is `PS1` set to? What does `echo "$COLUMNS"` say? What about `echo "$TERM"`? What does `print -P "%D{%a}"` say? What terminal software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The real question is: *what does `locale -a` returns?*

- First determine which locales you have installed in your computer with `locale -a`
- then set `LANG` `LC_*` accordingly.

Hint: In some systems you need to use `en_US.utf8` instead of `en_US.UTF8`